# for function just ends straightly in java script

Tags: javascript, html

I have just started to code html and java script and i have a problem with this code below, and i don't know why it just write the text with the last number that is set in for , please help me...

```js
function func() {
  var a;
  for (var j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
    a = "text";
    a += j;
    document.getElementById("page").innerHTML = document.getElementById(a).value + " ";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text1">
<input type="text" id="text2">
<input type="text" id="text3">
<input type="text" id="text4">
<input type="text" id="text5">
<input type="text" id="text6">

<input type="button" id="startbutton" value="tap" onclick="func()">

<br>

<p id="page"> </p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that you were not appending the HTML. You should use `+=` to add to existing `string`.

Also, there is a performance issue in retrieving the element every time and appending the html. It is better to store / update the values in a variable and at the end set the value of `innerHTML`.

Additionally, you should avoid creating the extra variable `a` to extract `id`. You can simply do the same as shown below.

```js
function func() {
  
  var html = "";
  for (var j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
    html += document.getElementById("text" + j).value + " ";
  }
  document.getElementById("page").innerHTML = html;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text1">
<input type="text" id="text2">
<input type="text" id="text3">
<input type="text" id="text4">
<input type="text" id="text5">
<input type="text" id="text6">

<input type="button" id="startbutton" value="tap" onclick="func()">

<br>

<p id="page"> </p>
```

Comment: @MohammadErfan - Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use setting innerHtml outside the loop!

```js
function func() {
  var text = '';
  for (var j = 1; j <= 6; j++) {
    var a = "text" + j;
    text += document.getElementById(a).value + " ";
  }
  
  document.getElementById("page").innerHTML = text
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text1">
<input type="text" id="text2">
<input type="text" id="text3">
<input type="text" id="text4">
<input type="text" id="text5">
<input type="text" id="text6">

<input type="button" id="startbutton" value="tap" onclick="func()">

<br>

<p id="page"> </p>
```